# Range.Text VBA, set data into variable

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get formatted data from an excel cell. This cell can contains special symbols like &,',",<,>, LF (End of Line). All this text content will be set inside of a xml structure. For this reason I have to get all this text and parse all special symbols and transformed to a character entity

```
(&amp; &apos; &quot; &lt;....)
```

To do this, first I have to load the data from cell in my code, it looks like:

```
Set beforeTransformation = Sheets(langId).Range("A46").Text
```

As official documentation says:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-text-property-excel

It's a read only property, so when I execute the VBA macro, next error is outputted,

> Compile error: Object required

The question is, which is the best way to get data from a cell and set it into a variable for future transformation?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove the word `Set` - It is only used for `Object` variables. `.Text` returns a string.

Comment: Thank you, now properly run.